# How do you link "o" and "s" in cursive font?

Tags: writing

I'm learning English cursive font recently. And I'm confused about how I can link the "o" and "s" together in words such as "those", "goes", and so on. Because the end of "o" is much higher than that of "s". By the way, I use the attachment as the model.[image]

Comment: here's a youtube video with a slow explanation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npIJI2hfyx0

Comment: "Font" is not really a word you can apply to characters created by handwriting. A font is a set of characters for printed type. Cursive is a handwriting style.

Comment: We can refer to a handwriting style or system as a *script*.

Comment: Here is connecting an O to an S https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASdcKyhXc4Q&list=PLNS_JCgJY7DlsoWpbuhF9d0CGEU7OMdZ2&index=5

Here is connecting an S to an O https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=06bvZayVKso&list=PLNS_JCgJY7DlsoWpbuhF9d0CGEU7OMdZ2&index=2&t=3s

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See image.  Used the word `lost` to illustrate with a real word.

[image]

Comment: OK.  Let's it see for capital O too.

Comment: Capital O wouldn't link to the next letter.  The loop would just hang.

Comment: Same is true for D, P, W too.  They just stand alone.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/MnLoX

Comment: The OP's chart is only one version of "cursive writing." Many of the letter forms are different form the ones I learned in school in the UK - and in the version I learned, upper case letters were never linked to the following lower case letters.

Comment: Yeah, I learned a cursive Q as kind of a fancy "2".